# IPython Notebook 2.0 Shell is not opening in the Browser

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I use Windows 7 and Anaconda python distribution. I updated the IPython 2.0 already so when I use the following command

```
conda update conda 

Fetching package metadata: ..
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda:
#
conda                     3.4.1                    py27_0
```

&

```
conda update ipython

Fetching package metadata: ..
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda:
#
ipython                   2.0.0                    py27_0
```

But when I tried to click/open Ipython (Py 2.7) Notebook icon.... Ipython Shell is not opening in the browser. I think the link is lost. Does anybody faced the same situation with the new version of IPython 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `conda update ipython-notebook`.

Comment: I actually used above command to update it. Its not opening in the browser.

Comment: its working! Good to see Jupyter era (IPython notebook 3.0.0)